# D3 Update and remove function doesnt work correctly

Tags: d3.js

I have another problem with my D3 chart.

I want to be able to adjust the data of my D3 chart and update the chart. To do this, I tried to delete the old "rect" elements and then update them.

My problem is that the "rect" elements are not deleted and  a new "g" tag is opened again and again.
I want the "rect" and "text" elements to be deleted in .heatmap_nodes and then the new "rect" and "text" elements will be created with the new data. My delete and update code will be find in the "Delete and Update" comment section.

Can anyone help me with this?

King Regards

Jegor

[image]

```js
            const data1= [
                {group:"A",variable:"v1",value: 98},{group:"A",variable:"v2",value:95},
                {group:"A",variable:"v3",value: 22},{group:"A",variable:"v4",value:14},
                {group:"A",variable:"v5",value: 59},{group:"A",variable:"v6",value:52},
                {group:"A",variable:"v7",value: 88},{group:"A",variable:"v8",value:20},
                {group:"A",variable:"v9",value: 99},{group:"A",variable:"v10",value:66},
                {group:"B",variable:"v1",value: 37},{group:"B",variable:"v2",value:50},
                {group:"B",variable:"v3",value: 81},{group:"B",variable:"v4",value:79},
                {group:"B",variable:"v5",value: 84},{group:"B",variable:"v6",value:91},
                {group:"B",variable:"v7",value: 82},{group:"B",variable:"v8",value:89},
                {group:"B",variable:"v9",value: 6},{group:"B",variable:"v10",value:67},
                {group:"C",variable:"v1",value: 96},{group:"C",variable:"v2",value:13},
                {group:"C",variable:"v3",value: 98},{group:"C",variable:"v4",value:10},
                {group:"C",variable:"v5",value: 86},{group:"C",variable:"v6",value:23},
                {group:"C",variable:"v7",value: 74},{group:"C",variable:"v8",value:47},
                {group:"C",variable:"v9",value: 73},{group:"C",variable:"v10",value:40},
                {group:"D",variable:"v1",value: 75},{group:"D",variable:"v2",value:18},
                {group:"D",variable:"v3",value: 92},{group:"D",variable:"v4",value:43},
                {group:"D",variable:"v5",value: 16},{group:"D",variable:"v6",value:27},
                {group:"D",variable:"v7",value: 76},{group:"D",variable:"v8",value:24},
                {group:"D",variable:"v9",value: 1},{group:"D",variable:"v10",value:87},
                {group:"E",variable:"v1",value: 44},{group:"E",variable:"v2",value:29},
                {group:"E",variable:"v3",value: 58},{group:"E",variable:"v4",value:55},
                {group:"E",variable:"v5",value: 65},{group:"E",variable:"v6",value:56},
                {group:"E",variable:"v7",value: 9},{group:"E",variable:"v8",value:78},
                {group:"E",variable:"v9",value: 49},{group:"E",variable:"v10",value:36},
                {group:"F",variable:"v1",value: 35},{group:"F",variable:"v2",value:80},
                {group:"F",variable:"v3",value: 8},{group:"F",variable:"v4",value:46},
                {group:"F",variable:"v5",value: 48},{group:"F",variable:"v6",value:102}
            ];

            const data2 = [
                {group:"A",variable:"v1",value: 1},{group:"A",variable:"v2",value:6},
                {group:"A",variable:"v3",value: 1},{group:"A",variable:"v4",value:6},
                {group:"A",variable:"v5",value: 2},{group:"A",variable:"v6",value:5},
                {group:"A",variable:"v7",value: 4},{group:"A",variable:"v8",value:6},
                {group:"A",variable:"v9",value: 4},{group:"A",variable:"v10",value:4},
                {group:"B",variable:"v1",value: 3},{group:"B",variable:"v2",value:7},
                {group:"B",variable:"v3",value: 5},{group:"B",variable:"v4",value:6},
                {group:"B",variable:"v5",value: 6},{group:"B",variable:"v6",value:5},
                {group:"B",variable:"v7",value: 7},{group:"B",variable:"v8",value:8}
            ];

        var i_region_static_id = "heatmap"
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById(i_region_static_id)
        var width_client = parentDiv.clientWidth;
        var i_height = 450;
        const margin = {top: 0, right: 35, bottom: 25, left: 70};
        const width = width_client - margin.left - margin.right;
        const height = i_height - margin.top - margin.bottom;  
        const labelGroup = "X-Label"
        const labelVars = "Y-Label"
        const color_start = "#f9f9f9"
        const colorEnd = "#6e69b3"
                
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Anfügen von svg Elementen zu #heatmap
        const svg = d3.select('#' + i_region_static_id)
                        // Anfügen von svg an #heatmap
                        .append("svg")
                            .attr("id", "svg_" + i_region_static_id)
                            .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width_client + margin.right} ${parseInt(i_height) + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)
                    
        const g_area = d3.select("#svg_" + i_region_static_id)                           
                        // Anfügen einer Gruppe an das SVG Element
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_area")
                        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

        const g_nodes = g_area
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_nodes")
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // X-Skalierung
        const x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
                    .range([0, width])
                    .padding(0.01);

        // X-Achse erstellen
        const xAxis = g_area
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_x_axis")
        xAxis.append("g")
            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_x_axis_value")
            .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .style("font-family", "arial")

        // Einfügen xAxis Label
        xAxis.append("text")
            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_x_axis_label")
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height + 50)
            .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
            .style("font-size", "18px")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(labelGroup);

        
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Y-Skalierung
        const y_scale = d3.scaleBand()
                    .range([height, 0])
                    .padding(0.03);
                    
        // Y-Achse erstellen
        const yAxis = g_area
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_y_axis")
        yAxis.append("g")
            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_y_axis_value")
            .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .style("font-family", "arial")

        // Einfügen yAxis Label
        yAxis.append("text")
            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_y_axis_label")
            .attr("y", - 45)         //Y ist hierbei die horizontale ausrichtung
            .attr("x", - height / 2) //X ist hierbei die vertikale ausrichtung
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
            .style("font-size", "18px")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(labelVars);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
        // ColorScale Legend
        const g_colorScale = g_area
                                .append("g")
                                    .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_colorLegend")

        // Erstelle yColorscale
        var yColorscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .range([height - 70, 0]);
        
        g_colorScale.append("g")
                    .attr("id" , i_region_static_id + "_colorscale_axis")
                    .attr("transform", `translate(${width + 30},${35})`)

        
        const g_def = g_colorScale.append("defs")
                    .append("linearGradient")
                        .attr("id", "grad")
                        .attr("x1", "0%")
                        .attr("x2", "0%")
                        .attr("y1", "0%")
                        .attr("y2", "100%");

        g_colorScale.append("rect")
                    .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_colorScale_legend")
                    .attr("x", width + 15)
                    .attr("y", 35)
                    .attr("rx", "4px")
                    .attr("width", 15)
                    .attr("height", height - 70)
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .style("fill", "url(#grad)");
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Erstellen eines Tooltip
        const tooltip = d3.select("#" + i_region_static_id)
            .append("div")
                .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "tooltip")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                .style("background-color", "white")
                .style("border", "solid")
                .style("border-width", "2px")
                .style("border-radius", "10px")
                .style("padding", "5px");

        const mouseover = function(event,d) {
            tooltip
                .style("visibility", "visible")
            d3.select(this).select("#" + i_region_static_id + "_node")
                .style("stroke", "black") 
                .style("stroke-width", "2px") 
        };

        const mousemove = function(event,d) {
            tooltip
                .text("Wert: " + d.value)
                .style("left", (event.offsetX + 20) + "px")
                .style("top", (event.offsetY + 95) + "px")
        };

        const mouseleave = function(d) {
            tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")
            d3.select(this).select("#" + i_region_static_id + "_node")
                .style("stroke", "none")
        };
        
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------               
        // Funktion für das Create, Update or Delete der D3 nodes
        function update_heatmap(data){
            const myGroups = data.map(function(d){return d.group})
            const myVars = data.map(function(d){return d.variable})
            const value = data.map(function(d){return d.value})
            const extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){;return d.value}); 

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            // Dynamisches Update der X-Achse
            const xAxisGroup = d3.select("#" + i_region_static_id + "_x_axis_value")
            x_scale.domain(myGroups)
            const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x_scale)
            xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall);

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            // Dynamisches Update der Y-Achse
            const yAxisGroup = d3.select("#" + i_region_static_id + "_y_axis_value")
            y_scale.domain(myVars)
            const yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y_scale)
            yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            // Color Skalierung       
            const myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([color_start, colorEnd])
                .domain([extent[0],(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50)])

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
            // ColorScale Legend
            const GradColors = [myColor(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50), myColor(extent[0])];

            // Fügt scales zur Achse hinzu
            const yAxisColorGroup = d3.select("#" + i_region_static_id + "_colorscale_axis")
            
            yColorscale.domain([0, Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50])

            const yAxisColorCall = d3.axisRight(yColorscale)
                                        .ticks(1)
            yAxisColorGroup.call(yAxisColorCall);

            g_def.selectAll("stop")
                .data(GradColors)
                .enter()
                .append("stop")
                .style("stop-color", function(d){return d;})
                .attr("offset", function(d,i){
                    return 100 * (i / (GradColors.length - 1)) + "%";
            })


            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
            // Create, Delete and Update
            const rect_nodes = g_nodes.selectAll("." + i_region_static_id + "_node_grp")
                                .data(data)

            const rect_node_grp = rect_nodes.enter()
                                            .append("g")
                                            .merge(rect_nodes)
                                                .attr("class", i_region_static_id + "_node_grp")
                                                .attr("group", function(d) {return d.group})
                                                .attr("variable",function(d) {return d.variable})
                                                .attr("value", function(d) {return d.value})
                                                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                                                .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                                                .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
                                                .on("click", function(d, i){console.log(i)})
            // Update Rect
            rect_nodes.selectAll("rect")
                            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_node")
                            .transition()
                            .delay(50)
                                .attr("x", function(d) {return x_scale(d.group)})
                                .attr("y", function(d) {return y_scale(d.variable)})
                                .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
                                .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
                                .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.value)})
            // Update Text
            rect_nodes.selectAll("text")
                            .attr("class", i_region_static_id + "_label")
                            .transition()
                            .delay(50)
                                .attr("x", function(d) {return x_scale(d.group)})
                                .attr("y", function(d) {return y_scale(d.variable)})
                                .attr("dx", x_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                .attr("dy", y_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                                .style("font-size", "14px")
                                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                                .text(function(d) {return (d.value)})

            // Create and append rect
            rect_node_grp.append("rect")
                            .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_node")
                            .transition()
                            .delay(50)
                                .attr("x", function(d) {return x_scale(d.group)})
                                .attr("y", function(d) {return y_scale(d.variable)})
                                .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
                                .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
                                .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.value)})

            // Create and append text
            rect_node_grp.append("text")  
                            .attr("class", i_region_static_id + "_label")
                            .transition()
                            .delay(50)
                                .attr("x", function(d) {return x_scale(d.group)})
                                .attr("y", function(d) {return y_scale(d.variable)})
                                .attr("dx", x_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                .attr("dy", y_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                                .style("font-size", "14px")
                                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                                .text(function(d) {return (d.value)})

            // Remove rect_nodes Elements
            rect_nodes.exit().remove()
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------               

        update_heatmap(data1)

        let i = 0;
        d3.interval(() => {
            if (i++ % 2 === 0) {
                update_heatmap(data2);
            } else {
                update_heatmap(data1);
            }

        }, 2000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>             
<!-- Code Vorschlage mit STRG+Leertaste aktivieren-->
    <head>              

        <meta charset="utf-8" />    <!-- Welche Sonderzeichen verwendet werden können -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    <!-- Wie sollte sich die Seite auf einem Handy verhalten -->
        <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>      <!-- title als Tag -->
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div id="heatmap"></div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    
    </body>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag--> 
</html>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag-->
```

**EDIT:**
Okay first of all, thank you for your help again. Your Codesnipes helps a lot. :)
With your help I rewrote my code to delete and recreate my "rec" and "text" elements (see Code Below). So far so good, but my data is not being updated correctly. The "Rect" and "Text Elements stays at their position. My X-Axis, moves correctly. Do you know what i am missing?

**EDIT:**
Okay, i missed the "Update" Part. Now it works and i need to adjust Text Value and my ColorScale. :) Do you know why the "Update" Part is not changing my Text Values, but my ToolTip Values?

**EDIT:**
The Problem war, that the data Values are bind to my "g" Element, so that the "rect" and "text" Elements used the old data values.
With the using of merge() function, my Text Values are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one rect and one text by `<g>` with the class heatmap_node_grp. What you can do is use `.each(...)` to update g childs elements

```
function update_heatmap(data) {
    ...
    const rect_nodes = g_nodes.selectAll("." + i_region_static_id + "_node_grp")
        .data(data)

    const rect_node_grp = rect_nodes.enter()
        .append("g")
        .each(function (d) {
            //Here you can happend element to your g
            d3.select(this).append('rect')
            d3.select(this).append('text')
        })
        .merge(rect_nodes)
        .attr("class", i_region_static_id + "_node_grp")
        .attr("group", function (d) {
            return d.group
        })
        .attr("variable", function (d) {
            return d.variable
        })
        .attr("value", function (d) {
            return d.value
        })
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
        .on("click", function (d, i) {
            console.log(i)
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            // here you can update your element inside g
            d3.select(this).select('rect')
                .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_node")
                .transition()
                .delay(50)
                .attr("x", x_scale(d.group))
                .attr("y", y_scale(d.variable))
                .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
                .style("fill", myColor(d.value))

            d3.select(this)
                .select('text')
                .attr("class", i_region_static_id + "_label")
                .transition()
                .delay(50)
                .attr("x", x_scale(d.group))
                .attr("y", y_scale(d.variable))
                .attr("dx", x_scale.bandwidth() / 2)
                .attr("dy", y_scale.bandwidth() / 2)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .style("font-size", "14px")
                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .text(d.value)
        })

    rect_nodes.exit().remove()
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help :) 
As far as I understood, (sorryfor asking, but I want to understand your code) :D
First you created a group "g" and with the each() function you added to each "g" a "text" and "rect" DOM. With another each() function you gave each "text" and "rect" DOM the attributes with the new database. Is that correct?

And the merge() function applies all updates to both rect_nodes and rect_nodes.enter() selections.

Comment: Yes, I use d3 selection pattern for g only and use `.each()` to update what's inside the g, as you can see I have 2 `.each()` one for create one for update. I don't need a `.each` on `.exit()` because g are removed with everything that is inside.

Comment: So the first each is the create section and the second one the update section, brilliant. I am new to D3js and just realize how much I still have to learn.

Comment: I updated my answer's code because `.each(function(d){...])` `d` is already the data element, so you don't have to use function on rect and text attributes

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `<g>` with the id 'heatmap_nodes' is recreated each time because of those lines

```
const g_nodes = g_area
     .append("g")
     .attr("id", i_region_static_id + "_nodes")
```

I'm not sure to understand your code but for info, that's how you create/update/delete with d3 selection :

```
  function createOrUpdate(data) {
        // selectAll give you all dom element of class "myRects" that match items in your data array
        const rectEns = svg.selectAll('.myRects')
            .data(data);

        // rectEns.enter() let you iterate through all your data items that didn't find a match with selectAll
        // CREATE
        rectEns.enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'myRects') // important this must match selectAll class
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .attr('width', 5)
            .attr('height', 5)
            .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 10)
            .merge(rectEns) // here you can merge ensemble to modify both created and updated // UPDATE
            .transition()
            .delay(500)
            .duration(500) // transition so you can see create and update
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
            .attr('x', (d) => d)

        // here exit() give you dom element that do not match any item in your data array
        //DELETE
        rectEns.exit().remove()

    }
```

Here a reference for `d3.selection` : https://observablehq.com/@d3/general-update-pattern?collection=@d3/d3-selection
Here is a reference for join syntax explanation: https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join

```js
 const svg = d3.select('svg')
    const data1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    const data2 = [30, 40, 50]

    function createOrUpdate(data) {
        // selectAll give you all dom element of class "myRects" that match items in your data array
        const rectEns = svg.selectAll('.myRects')
            .data(data);

        // rectEns.enter() let you iterate through all your data items that didn't find a match with selectAll
        // CREATE
        rectEns.enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'myRects') // important this must match selectAll class
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .attr('width', 5)
            .attr('height', 5)
            .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 10)
            .merge(rectEns) // here you can merge ensemble to modify both created and updated // UPDATE
            .transition()
            .delay(500)
            .duration(500) // transition so you can see create and update
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
            .attr('x', (d) => d)

        // here exit() give you dom element that do not match any item in your data array
        //DELETE
        rectEns.exit().remove()

    }

    /**
     * Same thing with join syntax
     * */
    function createOrUpdateJoin(data) {

         svg.selectAll('.myRects')
            .data(data)
            .join('rect')
            .attr('class', 'myRects')
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .attr('width', 5)
            .attr('height', 5)
            .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 10)
            .attr('fill', 'blue')
            .attr('x', (d) => d)


    }


    // update data1 then data 2
    let i = 0;
    d3.interval(() => {
        if (i++ % 2 === 0) {
            createOrUpdate(data1);
        } else {
            createOrUpdate(data2);
        }

    }, 2000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Code Vorschlage mit STRG+Leertaste aktivieren-->
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>    <!-- Welche Sonderzeichen verwendet werden können -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <!-- Wie sollte sich die Seite auf einem Handy verhalten -->
    <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>      <!-- title als Tag -->
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One further question. Now the update and the create works, however, due to the merge(), the exit().remove() no longer works. As you can the in my CodeSnipe a new "rect" or "text" DOM is created again and again to my g DOM "heatmap_node_grp". Do you know what iam doing wrong?

Comment: I answered your question on a new answer below